# AttributeError With `argparse`

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, optparse

So I am rewriting a ZIP Cracker that was published on *Violent Python* by TJ O'Connor, written on Python 2.7. The author used `optparse` but I went with `argparse`.

My code as follows:

```
import argparse
from threading import Thread
import zipfile
import io

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Unzips selected .zip using a dictionary attack", usage="CRARk.py -z zipname.zip -f file.txt")

# Creates -z arg
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the .zip file.")

# Creates -f arg
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the word-list/dictionary-list/password-list.")
args = parser.parse_args()


def extract_zip(zipFile, password):
    try:
        zipFile.extractall(pwd=password.encode())
        print("[+] Password for the .zip: {0}".format(password) + "\n")
    except:
        pass


def main(zip, dictionary):
    if (zip == None) | (dictionary == None):
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip)
    pass_file = io.open(dictionary, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    for line in pass_file.readlines():
        password = line.strip("\n")
        t = Thread(target=extract_zip, args=(zip_file, password))
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # USAGE - Project.py -z zipname.zip -f file.txt
    main(args.zip, args.dictionary)
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Project\Project.py", line 39, in <module>
    main(args.zip, args.dictionary)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'dictionary'
```

Now I am a bit unsure what that means. I tried renaming `args.dictionary` to `args.file` or alike but that ended up returning  an empty response on my terminal when I ran the code. As the following image shows, when I run the .py properly there is no reponse/output etc.

[image: The empty response when <code>args.file</code> is used instead of <code>args.dictionary</code>]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You named your argument `--file` and you're trying to access `args.dictionary`. Of course there's no `args.dictionary`.

Comment: So I should use `args.file` instead of `args.dictionary`? But then again, that doesnt explain the empty response I get from running the program when I use `args.file` instead of `args.dictionary`

Comment: Decryption failed.

Comment: Seems you are right @user2357112. But what I dont get is I why did it fail when I chose a password out of a password out of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ncorbuk/Python-Tutorial-Zip-Cracker-Bruteforce-Hacking-Info-Sec/master/darkweb2017-top10000.txt and then used it to make a simple password protected .zip. I had that paste as a .txt, saved as "Most Common 10k Passwords" (As seen on the image). Not sure what is wrong, as I created a similar zip using a few words I chose randomly and it worked. So not quite sure why cant I use a larger dictionary/password-list/word-list to bruteforce.

Answer (score 0):

With the argparse part of your code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Unzips selected .zip using a dictionary attack", usage="CRARk.py -z zipname.zip -f file.txt")

# Creates -z arg
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the .zip file.")

# Creates -f arg
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the word-list/dictionary-list/password-list.")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Sample runs:

```
2033:~/mypy$ python3 stack54431649.py -h
usage: CRARk.py -z zipname.zip -f file.txt

Unzips selected .zip using a dictionary attack

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -z , --zip    Location and the name of the .zip file.
  -f , --file   Location and the name of the word-list/dictionary-
                list/password-list.
1726:~/mypy$ python3 stack54431649.py
usage: CRARk.py -z zipname.zip -f file.txt
stack54431649.py: error: the following arguments are required: -z/--zip, -f/--file
1726:~/mypy$ python3 stack54431649.py -z zippy -f afile
Namespace(file='afile', zip='zippy')
```

That means that I can access the values with

```
args.file    # 'afile'
args.zip     # 'zippy'
main(args.zip, args.file)
```

In `main`

```
if zip is None:    # better than zip == None
```

but since these 2 arguments are required they will never be `None`.

From there the question is whether the value of `zip` is the name of a valid `zip` file, and whether you can open `dictionary`.

Comment: Yea I am assuming that touches what @user2347112 said, where I used `args.dictionary` instead of `args.file` right?

But that still does not explain why cant I decipher/bruteforce a .zip I created using a password from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ncorbuk/Python-Tutorial-Zip-Cracker-Bruteforce-Hacking-Info-Sec/master/darkweb2017-top10000.txt and then using the .txt to bruteforce it